# Loading variables into memory from cat

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a list of variables defined in a file on a server and I'd like to load those variables into a script on my local machine without saving them to a file on a my local machine.

File name on server is `variables.properties`

Assume the content of `variables.properties` is:

```
var1="string1"
var2="string2"
var3="string3"
var4="string4"
```

Right now I can get the content of that file back to my local machine like this:

```
!#/bin/sh

vars=$(ssh user@server "cat /variable.properties")
echo $vars
```

Is there a way that I can load each of those variables into my script from the `$vars` variable so that they have the same name and value on my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `eval "$vars"`

It seems to work for me.

Comment: What exactly does `eval` do?

Comment: @nkon `eval` takes a string and evaluates it as if you typed it on the command line.

Comment: @nkon: Florin is right. So you do need to be careful with it because if variable.properties contains any commands such as `rm -rf $HOME` they would be executed.

Comment: @ZanLynx thanks for that info.  I didn't know that it had that much power.

Comment: You need quotes around `$vars`  or spacing won't be preserved and you may run into issues with wildcard characters.

Answer (score 2):

Any easier method, without running a script, would be:

```
eval `ssh user@server cat /variable.properties`
```

Comment: But your above method is pretty much exactly the same. `source` is the same as `eval` in that it executes everything in the file as a command.

Comment: @ZanLynx You're right. For some reason I was under the impression source would only take variable declarations. I removed my edits.

Comment: You need quotes around command substitution or spacing won't be preserved and you may run into issues with wildcard characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you use bash as your script interpreter instead of sh, you could do

```
source <(ssh user@server "cat /variable.properties")
```

or perhaps

```
scp -q user@server:/variable.properties .
. variable.properties
```

Comment: Note that you need `bash` 4 or above for the first one as older ones had issues with that syntax. Also not that that syntax is not `bash` specific. It comes from `ksh93` and works as well with `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod +x /path/to/variables.properties
. /path/to/variables.properties
```

This sources the file and create var1, var2 ....
This is more of a usual way to approach this kind of problem than using cat.

Comment: And why the down vote - this is correct  and yeah it does not use cat.  Consider UUOC if you know what that means.

Comment: The comment was not aimed you, nkon.  Normally people leave a comment on a downvote telling you the objection.